# How to navigate by spaces in Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

More specifically: **How to navigate to the closest space to the left of the cursor in Visual studio code?**

I've been looking around on google and even the shortcuts answers on SO but there's nothing.

EDIT 1: Clarification

Consider this text, and the cursor is at the caret:

```
This is a sentence
                  ^
```

Pressing this shortcut moves the cursor here:

```
This is a sentence
         ^
```

Edit 2: this is what Ctrl+Left does

```
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
                                      ^
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
                                   ^
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
                              ^
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
                           ^
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
                      ^
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
                    ^
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
                 ^
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
             ^
```

Edit 2: This is what I'm looking for:

```
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
                                      ^
... type="x" href="/a/path/to/file.css"
             ^
```

Comment: downvotes are fine and expected for this kind of question, but at least point out the obvious "Have you tried searching google for...." and be useful

Comment: Yeah, it goes to word boundaries, those aren't only spaces.  Close as you are going to get though without an extension.

Comment: Good to know, thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>leftArrow</kbd>

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+left",
  "command": "cursorWordStartLeft",
  "when": "textInputFocus"
}
```

Comment: Ctrl+Left moves the cursor like this from (0) to (7) and each ctrl+left in between: **`type="x" (7)href(6)="/(5)a/(4)path/(3)to/(2)file.(1)css(0)`**

Comment: Looking for: **`type="x" (1)href="/a/path/to/file.css(0)`**